# Cannot create local Cloud Foundry deployment behind proxy

Tags: cloud-foundry

I cannot set my api endpoint when I am behind my corporate proxy. I am following the Cloud Foundry deployment steps located on the [CF GitHub page](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite/blob/master/docs/deploy-cf.md#try-your-cloud-foundry-deployment). Whenever I run the command `cf api --skip-ssl-validation https://api.10.244.0.34.xip.io`, I get this error:

```
$ cf api --skip-ssl-validation https://api.10.244.0.34.xip.io
Setting api endpoint to https://api.10.244.0.34.xip.io...
FAILED
Error performing request: Get https://api.10.244.0.34.xip.io/v2/info: read tcp <my ip>: connection reset by peer
```

My vagrant VM is running, and `bosh cck` shows no errors. I have tried setting my `no_proxy` as well, as instructed from their readme:

```
$ printenv
...
no_proxy=192.168.50.4,*.xip.io
```

However, if I disconnect from the company's network and use my own network connection at home, then I do not get the error. Is there something else I need to do to be able to create the deployment behind a proxy?

Comment: Have you tried setting env. variable : HTTP_PROXY. http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/installcf/http-proxy.html

Comment: Yes, my http_proxy and https_proxy are both set. I cannot use the ``cf set-env`` command, though, because it says I need to set an api endpoint first (which is the problem I am having).

Comment: Are you able to curl the following URL at all? https://api.10.244.0.34.xip.io

Comment: It doesn't look like it. I get the error ``Gateway Timeout: Server error - server 10.244.0.34 is unreachable at this moment. Please retry the request or contact your adminstrator.``

Comment: Try adding `CF_TRACE=true ` before your command and see what call is failing, exactly.

Comment: `cf set-env` sets ENV variables on an application pushed to CF, you don't have any apps yet because you can't target the API yet.  `CF_TRACE=true` also won't help because it let's you get trace details from API requests made by the `cf` CLI, but you're not able to talk to the API yet.  Have you run `bin/add-route` from the BOSH-Lite directory? https://github.com/cloudfoundry/bosh-lite/blame/d6dbc035641e7794a88151c5be83f0c85782dea2/README.md#L83-L87